# Images in slider appear in odd order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

Can anyone explain to me that why 1 and 3 images are shown when next image length is 0. When comes on 3rd images its length is 0 so according to condition store first image in it but I cant understand whats happening

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(rotateImages, 4000);
});

function rotateImages(){
  var currImage = $(".slider div.current");
  var nextimage = currImage.next();
  if (nextimage.length == 0){
    nextimage = $(".slider div:first");
  }

  nextimage.css({
    opacity: 0.0
  }).addClass("current").animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px black;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}

.slider div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.slider div.previous {
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider div.current {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

<div class="slider">
  <div class="current">
    <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/4467/screenshots/257352/abraham-lewis.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/4467/screenshots/245651/robot.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/4467/screenshots/212240/brainoid.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please take care when formatting your code and describing the problem. That's why you have so many down and close votes. I've edited the question so hopefully it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: probably because you never remove the current class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have not removed your current class therefore whilst the next image is fading in, you still have your current image visible.  I have also changed the below so that the css handles the animation

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(rotateImages, 4000);
});

function rotateImages() {
  var currImage = $(".slider div.current");
  var nextimage = currImage.next();
  if (nextimage.length == 0) {
    nextimage = $(".slider div:first");
  }

  currImage.removeClass('current');       // this is what is missing from your code
  nextimage.addClass("current");
}
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px black;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}

.slider div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
   
  transition: opacity 1s; /* let css handle the animation */
  opacity:0;
}

.slider div.previous {
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider div.current {
  z-index: 2;
  opacity:1;          /* let css handle the animation */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

<div class="slider">
  <div class="current">
    <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/4467/screenshots/257352/abraham-lewis.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/4467/screenshots/245651/robot.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/4467/screenshots/212240/brainoid.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear your previous "current" class when setting new div to that. Also looking at your css, it seems you need "previous" class as well(?).

You need to do something like this :

```
 var prevImage = $(".slider div.previous");
 prevImage.removeClass("previous");
 currImage.removeClass("current").addClass("previous");
```

This takes care of `.current` and `.previous`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(rotateImages, 4000);
});

function rotateImages() {
  var currImage = $(".slider div.current");
  var nextimage = currImage.next();
  if (nextimage.length == 0) {
    nextimage = $(".slider div:first");
  }

 var prevImage = $(".slider div.previous");
 prevImage.removeClass("previous");
  currImage.removeClass("current").addClass("previous");
  nextimage.css({
    opacity: 0.0
  }).addClass("current").animate({
    opacity: 1.0
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px black;
  margin: 5rem auto;
}

.slider div {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

.slider div.previous {
  z-index: 1;
}

.slider div.current {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">

<div class="slider">
  <div class="current">
    <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/4467/screenshots/257352/abraham-lewis.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/4467/screenshots/245651/robot.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="https://dribbble.s3.amazonaws.com/users/4467/screenshots/212240/brainoid.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```